# Why Pagination with latest() method got some ID from previous page where it shoulnd't be like that?

Tags: laravel-10

When i paginate to next page of the table, i got some ID that the same from previous page where it shouldn't be like that.

This is my contoller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDjj4.png)
this is how it resulted, the ID 1141 showed again in page 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfzHY.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9OJd.png)